# how to determine whether a field exists?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database-cursor

I'm connecting to my *mongodb* using *pymongo*:

```
client = MongoClient()
mongo = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
mongo_db = mongo['test']
mongo_coll = mongo_db['test']   #Tweets database
```

I have a cursor and am looping through every record:

```
cursor = mongo_coll.find() 
for record in cursor:    #for all the tweets in the database
    try:
      msgurl = record["entities"]["urls"]    #look for URLs in the tweets
    except:
      continue
```

The reason for the `try/except` is because if `["entities"]["urls"]` does not exist, it errors out.

**How can I determine whether `["entities"]["urls"]` exists?**

Comment: also please correct my terminology of "field"

Comment: Just to add to @martingreber answer, to check if the field exists and the value is not null. mongo_coll.find({ $and:[ {"entities.urls": {$exists:1}}, {"entities.urls": {$not: {$type:10}}} ]})

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Record is a dictionary in which the key `"entities"` links to another dictionary, so just check to see if `"urls"` is in that dictionary.

```
if "urls" in record["entities"]:
```

If you just want to proceed in any case, you can also use get.

```
msgurl = record["entities"].get("urls")
```

This will cause msgurl to equal None if there is no such key.

Comment: thanks so much! what about checking whether record["entities"] exists?

Comment: You can do the same thing: either `if "entities" in record:` or `record.get("entities")`.

Comment: awesome thanks so much. ill accept as soon as i'm able (5 min)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not familiar with pymongo, but why don't you change your query so it only returns results that contain `"urls"`? Something like:

```
mongo_coll.find({"entities.urls": {$exists:1}})
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/